# How can I get committed and pushed files in Github Workflow for Lint?

Tags: github-actions, eslint, lint

I have a lint.yaml as a Workflow for GitHub Actions, which should check the files with ESLint, whether they are linted. It should only check and not fix. But I want to run lint only on the committed and pushed files and not on the whole project.

Is there a way in the yaml to only take the changed files and run lint over them?

Comment: That entirely depends on how the linter is currently called, and we can't see that.